# Why is KnowledgeArticleVersion not in Schema.getGlobalDescribe()?

Tags: apex, knowledge, describesobject, schema

It's a bit inconvenient that this returns null:

```
system.debug( Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('KnowledgeArticleVersion') );
```

While this does not:

```
system.debug( KnowledgeArticleVersion.getSObjectType().getDescribe() );
```

Comment: Does your current user have a license to knowledge? Since it's a standard object I believe the latter type will always be able to reference it while apex run with sharing won't show inaccessible SObjects in the describe if memory serves.

Comment: It's a dev org but the user should have the right license as it can create articles.

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I am also facing same issue. Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('KnowledgeArticleVersion') returns Attempt to de-reference a null object. User does not have any license issue. A SOQL on KnowledgeArticleVersion returns results.

Comment: Hi Dave, please see the answer on this question for help moving forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
DescribeSObjectResult objType = KnowledgeArticleVersion.getSObjectType().getDescribe();
Map<String, SObjectField> fields = objType.fields.getMap();
Set<String> fieldSet = fields.keySet();

for(String s:fieldSet)
{
    SObjectField fieldToken = fields.get(s);
    DescribeFieldResult selectedField = fieldToken.getDescribe();
    System.debug(selectedField.getName());
}
```

KnowledgeArticleVersion is not available for Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get().

Comment: Getting better at development eh ;)

Comment: Significantly. I actually didn't realize who posted the question until after the fact ;)