# List Knowledge Articles on Visualforce Page

Tags: knowledge, describesobject

I am working on KnowledgeArticleVersion and want to show the list of articles on Visual force page.

```
SObjectType objToken = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('KnowledgeArticleVersion');
DescribeSObjectResult objDef = objToken.getDescribe();
Map<String, SObjectField> fields = objDef.fields.getMap();

Set<String> fieldSet = fields.keySet();
for(String s:fieldSet)
{
    SObjectField fieldToken = fields.get(s);
    DescribeFieldResult selectedField = fieldToken.getDescribe();
    System.debug(selectedField.getName());
}
```

When I try to run this through apex, I get an exception

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object.

I am able to run this SOQL Query using same object,

```
SELECT Id, Title FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion WHERE
PublishStatus='Online' AND language ='en_US'
```

The framework that we are using does not allow this SOQL Query to be used and does a describe and fetches fields dynamically.

Can someone please provide a help or pointer on this ?

Comment: Which line are you getting the exception on?

Comment: On this line DescribeSObjectResult objDef = objToken.getDescribe();

Comment: [Why is KnowledgeArticleVersion not in Schema.getGlobalDescribe()?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11589/why-is-knowledgearticleversion-not-in-schema-getglobaldescribe) appears to have a work-around.

Comment: Keith, that link does not have any workaround. There is no license issue which is mentioned in other link. In fact, I also posted my comment to inquire if there was any solution.

Comment: The workaround is using `KnowledgeArticleVersion.getSObjectType()` instead of `Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('KnowledgeArticleVersion')`.

Comment: Oh, I think I overlooked it. Let me check to see if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use the workaround as mentioned in the above comments by fellow members. KnowledgeArticleVersion.getSObjectType().getDescribe() instead of Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('KnowledgeArticleVersion').

This is not truly dynamic in nature since I had to check in the code for name of Object and make a database call accordingly.

Comment: Marking this as answer since there was no other way found to get Knowledge Articles